# Converting Theano-based Keras model definition to TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, theano, keras

When converting Theano-based Keras model definition to TensorFlow, is it enough to change the order of `input_shape` on the input layer?

For example, the following layer

```
Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height))
```

will be replaced as

```
Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
```

Note: I don't want to use `dim_ordering='th'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [Francois Chollet](https://github.com/fchollet):

> I think the question means "what `input_shape` should I pass to my
>   first layer given that I'm using TensorFlow and that my default
>   setting for `dim_ordering` is `"tf"`". The answer is yep, that's how you
>   do it, `(img_width, img_height, 3)`.
>
> Important to note that if you want to load saved models that were
>   trained with Theano with `dim_ordering="th"`, into a model definition
>   for TF with `dim_ordering="tf"`, you will need to convert the convolution
>   kernels. Keras has utils for that.