# How to convert parameters saved from theano model (.pkl / .npz) to tensorflow format .ckpt?

Tags: theano, tensorflow, theano-cuda

I have found this link [Converting Theano-based Keras model definition to TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730483/converting-theano-based-keras-model-definition-to-tensorflow), but I do not use keras at all.

Are there other ways to do that?