# How to convert Theano backend channels-last model , first to Tensorflow backend model, then to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano, tensorflow-lite

## Problem

I have a trained model (that is not mine) on which I can make inferences with Theano backend. I need to run it on Android, so I try to convert this model to Tensorflow lite (`.tflite`).

Before converting it to `.tflite`, I try to make the model work with tensorflow backend but I can't do it properly. (python with keras)

## What works

This is what I do with the theano model, theano backend, channels-last ordering, it works fine :

```
with open('Model/definition.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())
model.load_weights('Model/weights.h5')
p = model.predict_proba(preprocessed_data)
print_results(p)
```

the model has only two outputs (detected or not detected) and it works fine.

## What does not work

When I just switch backend to tensorflow and run the same code, the model does not detect anything anymore.

## What I have tried already

I first thought it was a dim ordering problem as I saw on this pages for example : [Converting Theano-based Keras model definition to TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730483/converting-theano-based-keras-model-definition-to-tensorflow).

- A theano model should use channels-first dimensions.
- A tensorflow
  model should use channels-last dimensions.

There is also the script from this thread that I tried : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5374

It does not work for me because I think that my weights are already channels-last ordering ! (This is what I supposed from [netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/), see picture on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uuFz.png)

Last thing I tried was [convert_all_kernels_in_model()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/convert_all_kernels_in_model), but I got this error :

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/kernel
>        [[{{node _retval_conv2d_1/kernel_0_0}}]]

## Question

What do you think guy I need to do on my model to make it run with tensorflow backend (in order to convert it to tflite...) ???

Comment: I think this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/wiki/Converting-convolution-kernels-from-Theano-to-TensorFlow-and-vice-versa) will help you to convert your theano model. It will also convert your weights according to tensorflow requirement.

Comment: thanks @kruxx , the problem with this solution in that link is that my nodes mostly are "Conv2D" (as shown here https://i.imgur.com/eTqOitU.png ).
So in the for loop  
`for layer in model.layers:
   if layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Convolution1D', 'Convolution2D':
[...]`  
  
 it does not convert the nodes.
I tried adding a if condition for 'Conv2D' but I get the error :
  
'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'W'. Is this a old version of Keras that used Conv2D ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing it wright ? They often say that I have to load the weights on a tensorflow model... Do I have to create a new tensorflow model instead of loading the configuration.json fil (made with theano) ? If yes, how do I know the parameters ?